# Get specific value from JSON string

Tags: json, ajax

I'm trying to get a simple value out of my json string. It seems to be harder than I thought. How can I reach for example the 'name' of the first ModuleAction object in the following JSON (the first array is called 'data'):

```
[
   {
      "ModuleController":{
         "id":"3"
      },
      "ModuleActionModuleController":[
         {
            "id":"4",
            "module_action_id":"1",
            "module_controller_id":"3",
            "ModuleAction":{
               "id":"1",
               "name":"Overzicht",
               "action":"index"
            }
         },
         {
            "id":"5",
            "module_action_id":"2",
            "module_controller_id":"3",
            "ModuleAction":{
               "id":"2",
               "name":"Detail",
               "action":"view"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Here's my best attempt:

```
data[0].ModuleActionModuleController[0].id
```

But I've got the error:

```
add:93 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Object.success (add:93)
    at j (jquery-2.1.0.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.1.0.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery-2.1.0.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-2.1.0.min.js:4)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? :)

**EDIT**

Here's the ajax function that returns the data JSON string:

```
$(function() {
    $('#PageModuleId').on('change', function(){
        var formData = $('#PageAddForm').serialize();

        // POST to server

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo $this->here; ?>',
            dataType: 'text',
            data: formData,
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data[0].ModuleActionModuleController[0].ModuleAction.name);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I reach for example the '**name**' of the first ModuleAction
>   object in the following JSON?

It appears to me that you are just missing the next child element: `ModuleActionModuleController.ModuleAction.name`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{"ModuleController":{"id":"3"},"ModuleActionModuleController":[{"id":"4","module_action_id":"1","module_controller_id":"3","ModuleAction":{"id":"1","name":"Overzicht","action":"index"}},{"id":"5","module_action_id":"2","module_controller_id":"3","ModuleAction":{"id":"2","name":"Detail","action":"view"}}]}' );
//alert( obj.ModuleActionModuleController[0].ModuleAction.name );
document.body.innerHTML = obj.ModuleActionModuleController[0].ModuleAction.name;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Brien! Do you think I should do something sort-a-like with my returned AJAX data (see edit in my original post)?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```js
var JSON = {
    "data": [
   {
      "ModuleController":{
         "id":"3"
      },
      "ModuleActionModuleController":[
         {
            "id":"4",
            "module_action_id":"1",
            "module_controller_id":"3",
            "ModuleAction":{
               "id":"1",
               "name":"Overzicht",
               "action":"index"
            }
         },
         {
            "id":"5",
            "module_action_id":"2",
            "module_controller_id":"3",
            "ModuleAction":{
               "id":"2",
               "name":"Detail",
               "action":"view"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
};

 alert(JSON.data[0].ModuleActionModuleController[0].ModuleAction.id);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply akanksha-hp. I tried to do the same thing in my code, but it isn't working. Perhaps, it's because the JSON data string is the output of my AJAX call? See edit :)